# Apple - Suspend / refund in-app auto-renewable subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iPhone/iPad application that offers a monthly subscription to a service. Although, this service is totally useless during 2 months in the whole year.

Is there any way to either suspend all my users subscription for 2 months, or give them a 2 months refund every year so they don't pay for a useless service ?

Comment: I don't think so. You could put it on sale during those months, but any price change requires all your users to re-enable automatic renewals, so you'll lose renewals. It seems like the best way to handle it is through marketing--clarify that they're paying monthly for an annual service. Or perhaps you can come up with some other content or functionality that makes it not so useless in the off-season?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good talk with an Apple employee, it is not possible to suspend an auto-renewable product.

Also, 0$ subscriptions do not exist outside NewsStand apps for the moment.

In order to solve our problem, we will have to delete the in-app product in iTunes Connect. This will automatically cancel all active subscriptions we have so the users will not be charged for nothing.

A big downside to this solution is that we will lose all current subscribers, so next year we have to build up a new subscriber bank from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give two months for free to your users instead of refund them.

Comment: You’re right, you can’t create a free in-app purchase. My fault. Anyway you can create an standard in-app subscription and make it special adding contents or new stuff for your costumers.

Comment: The current answer is slightly out of date - you **can** have free in-app purchases, but only for Newsstand apps. You can have free subscriptions in such applications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you found any better alternative, since posting your answer about canceling all subscribers every year?

In addition to 1-year subscriptions, apple lets you do other terms as well, including 1-month subscriptions, for both renewable and non-renewable subscriptions.

Maybe you could make your in-app UI look as if the user is signing up for a long-term subscription, but behind the scenes, your app only sends a 1-month non-renewable subscription request to apple. Then, each month, your app automatically requests another 1-month subscription, and another... just skip the months you want to skip.

The user fills out the subscription form in your UI 1 time. Your app logic remembers how many times to start a new 1-month subscription.