# What happens when you set "cleared for sale" to "no" for an auto-renewable subscription in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I'm considering implementing an auto-renewable subscription in my iOS app, but I want it to finish after January 2013.  My app is a time-based app that no longer makes sense after January.  From what I read on this SO question: [Apple - Suspend / refund in-app auto-renewable subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521563/apple-suspend-refund-in-app-auto-renewable-subscription), if I "delete" the in-app product in iTunes Connect, all active subscriptions will automatically cancel.  I'm thinking that I could delete the product in January, and thereby cancel all active subscriptions.

From what I can see, there is no way to "delete" an in-app product.  You can only set it to be not "Cleared for Sale".  Does anyone know:

1. If there really is a way to delete an in-app product in iTunes
   Connect after the product is live
2. If setting "cleared for sale" to "no" for an auto-renewable
   subscription will do effectively what I want: cancel all active
   in-app subscriptions

Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation dreadpirateyan.  Did you need to change "cleared for sale" to no?

Comment: according to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html) "Removing a product from sale prevents auto-renewable subscriptions from renewing, but it doesn’t keep users from being able to restore products that they purchased previously."